# How to merge two different array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would need to combine two different fields.
In the first field I generate days of the month. I want to list all days of the month.
I would like to add a second field to them, where there are items for each day. But, for example, there are no items on weekends or on other days. Ie. that field two will always have fewer items.
The second field is tightened from the DB.
I would need to do a JOIN like in MySQL for the first field.

It occurred to me that in MySQL it would be possible to make a temporary table with a given month and link it here, but I don't think it's right.

```
$arrayDate = [0 => '20210401',1 => '20210402',2 => '20210403',3 => '20210404',4 => '20210405',5 => '20210406',6 => '20210407',7 => '20210408',8 => '20210409',9 => '20210410',10 => '20210411',11 => '20210412',12 => '20210413',13 => '20210414',14 => '20210415',15 => '20210416',16 => '20210417',17 => '20210418',18 => '20210419',19 => '20210420',20 => '20210421',21 => '20210422',22 => '20210423',23 => '20210424',24 => '20210425',25 => '20210426',26 => '20210427',27 => '20210428',28 => '20210429',29 => '20210430'];
$arrayItem[35] = ['id' => 35, 'date' => '20210401', 'item' => 'aaaa'];
$arrayItem[36] =  ['id' => 36, 'date' => '20210402', 'item' => 'bbbb'];
$arrayItem[37] =  ['id' => 36, 'date' => '20210430', 'item' => 'cccc'];

// i need output
20210401 - aaaa
20210402 - bbbb
20210403 - empty
20210404 - empty
...
20210430 - cccc
```

EDIT: I use nested loops, but I still can't get the right output

```
    foreach ($arrayDate as $date) {
        foreach ($arrayItem as $item) {
            if ($date == $item['date']) {
                bdump($item['date']);
            } else {
                bdump($date);
            }
        }
    }

bdump($item['date']) = '20210401', '20210402', '20210430'
bdump($date) = '20210401', '20210401', '20210402', '20210402', '20210403', '20210403', '20210403', '20210404', '20210404', '20210404', '20210405', '20210405', '20210405' ....
```

Comment: Use nested loops. The main loop loops over `$arrayDate`. The inner loop loops over `$arrayItem`, searching for the matching date. If it finds it, it prints the item.

Comment: In the database you would do this with a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables.

Comment: To make it more efficient, you can convert `$arrayItem` into an associative array that uses the `date` as the key. Then you don't need the inner loop, just access the correspond element of the associative array.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how convert `$arrayItem` into an associative array that uses the `date`. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php) you create a array from $arrayItem with date as key.
$dateItem is an array like

```
array (
  20210401 => "aaaa",
  20210402 => "bbbb",
  20210430 => "cccc",
)
```

The output you can do with a simple foreach.

```
$dateItem = array_column($arrayItem,'item','date');
foreach($arrayDate as $date){
  echo $date.' '.($dateItem[$date] ?? 'empty')."<br>\n";
}
```

Note:

With

```
array_column($arrayItem,null,'date')
```

you get a two-dimensional array with a date as a key that can be used.

```
array (
  20210401 => 
  array (
    'id' => 35,
    'date' => "20210401",
    'item' => "aaaa",
  ),
  20210402 => 
  array (
    'id' => 36,
    'date' => "20210402",
    'item' => "bbbb",
  ),
  20210430 => 
  array (
    'id' => 36,
    'date' => "20210430",
    'item' => "cccc",
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I assign this for all days? E.g. April is 30 days old. I need to view all 30 days and if there is a match, assign the items. Array `$arrayItem` actually contains more properties that I need to get to. That's the way I would lose them.

Comment: The solution shows it for all days. $arrayItem can also be larger. The 'date' field must always be unique.

Comment: I'm sorry, it works. Great. How could I get an `id` in `$arrayItem`, for example, and possibly other items such as color, weight? Thx

Comment: Thank you once again. I added `$dateItem2 = array_column($arrayItem,'id','date');` and it works.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, see my note in the answer.